# Trouble installing caldecott osx mountain lion

Tags: cloud-foundry, appfog

I'm having trouble installing caldecott on osx mountain lion. I keep getting this error:

> $ sudo gem install caldecott --no-rdoc --no-ri

ERROR:  Error installing caldecott:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
    /Users/Jay/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby extconf.rb
```

checking for main() in -lssl... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

/Users/Jay/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:369:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.

Here is my gem list:

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

addressable (2.2.8)
af (0.3.18.11)
bundler (1.2.3)
cfoundry (0.4.15)
clouseau (0.0.2)
interact (0.5.1, 0.4.8)
json_pure (1.6.7)
manifests-vmc-plugin (0.4.19)
mime-types (1.19)
mothership (0.3.5)
multi_json (1.4.0)
multipart-post (1.1.5)
rake (10.0.2)
rb-readline (0.4.2)
rest-client (1.6.7)
rubygems-bundler (1.1.0)
rubyzip (0.9.9)
rvm (1.11.3.5)
terminal-table (1.4.5)
tunnel-dummy-vmc-plugin (0.0.2)
uuidtools (2.1.3)
vmc (0.4.7)

Any ideas on how I can get this to work. Or is there another way to tunnel to my mongodb on appfog?

Answer (score 1):

First thing I notice is that your running gem install as root. If you're using RVM, you don't need to do this.

The likely issue here is that you don't have a C compiler installed, Caldecott uses native libraries and it requires them to be built. In the case of OS X, you need to install xcode. Do you have that installed?

Comment: You'll need Xcode *with command line tools* installed, the process for which has changed in Mavericks. Take a look over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19066647/xcode-5-0-error-installing-command-line-tools