# Xcode 5.0 Error installing command line tools

Tags: ios, xcode, pascal, lazarus

I just downloaded the last version for Xcode (5.0) and need it develop some Pascal codes on Lazarus. However, the installation requires me to use command line tools, which have a problem downloading. When I click install, the program sends me this error message: "Failed to install 'Command Line Tolls' An unknown error occurred.  Please try again later."

I have also tried using other IDEs, like lightweight, but they all require Free Pascal, which is the tool that needs command line tools.

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Try again later, it is probably a transient server/network error. [See this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9329325/451475)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

#### Xcode 5.1 and OSX 10.9.

`xcode-select --install` worked with version 2333, failed with version 2003. So, try `xcode-select --install` and if that does not work download as described below.

#### arly February 2014

`xcode-select --install` has been reporting that "Can't install the software because it is not currently available from the Software Update server". In late February 2014 the command started only displaying help. The **solution** is to download directly, see below.

#### Xcode 5.0.1 and Mavericks 10.9

The command line tools are no longer available via Xcode.

#### Direct download

They must be downloaded from the [Apple Developer site](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action#). This requires signing in with a developer account.

Or they can be installed from the terminal using `xcode-select --install` for certain version of xcode-select`.

For more complete information see this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9329325/451475)

Try again later, it is probably a transient server/network error.

See this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9329325/451475)

**Xcode 5** screenshot:
[image]

Comment: By the way, if you are under Mavericks now the "Command Line Tools" are not listed anymore: you have to download them manually from [Apple Developers' portal](http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/command_line_tools_os_x_mavericks_for_xcode__late_october_2013/command_line_tools_os_x_mavericks_for_xcode__late_october_2013.dmg)

Comment: @koda The above link does not work, it is linked to your session.

Comment: @koda: Just to be sure: in 5.0.1/10.9 the absence of an entry for Command Line Tools in the Downloads pane doesn't mean that the tools are already installed, but means that they can't be installed that way (any more)?

Comment: I've posted [a related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19623124/656912) about the consequences of following this procedure.

Comment: What I find very bizarre about this is that Apple said at WWDC that the command line tools would come with Xcode, the dialog box that pops up implies the same thing.  It claims you have a choice: install the command line tools or install Xcode.  Yet installing Xcode doesn't seem to have installed the tools for me.

Comment: Under Mavericks (OSX 10.9) and having just upgraded to latest Xcode (v. 5.02), running "xcode-select --install” from terminal, as suggested, worked immediately.

Comment: xcode-select --install seems to not be working anymore "Can't install the software because is not currently available from the Software Update server".

Comment: Been dead for months. Login and download the DMG.

Answer (score 3):

Download and re-install didn't work for me. Had to go to Xcode and choose *which* install to use in Preferences/Locations. (I had accumulated several from Xcode 4, 5 and 6.)

[image]

Comment: This helped me on Yosemite version 10.10.3 (Mac mini Late 2012) - Xcode Version 6.3.2 (6D2105).